# Default values of an optional parameter

Tags: list, compiler-errors, dart, future, optional-parameters

I have a future and I want first optional parameter of that future to be an empty list. But `dartanalyzer myFile.dart` returns this error:

```
[error] Default values of an optional parameter must be constant
(/home/user/projects/project/lib/myFolder/myFile.dart, line 7, col 48)
```

My code:

```
Future<dynamic> myFuture([List<Node> content = []]) async {
/*...*/
}
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to use a constant as default parameter. To define a constant list you need to use the prepending `const` keyword:

```dart
Future<dynamic> myFuture([List<Node> content = const []]) async {
/*...*/
}
```

Comment: Works as expected, thank you. I had tried to add const before I asked, but at the wrong place in my code.

Comment: if you try to add to this list, it throws `Cannot add to an unmodifiable list`